# Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "name"

Tags: xml

Getting the following error:

> (Configuration) :org.xml.sax.SAXException:Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".

while uploading the below xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE UWLConfiguration PUBLIC "-//SAP//UWL1.0//EN" "uwl_configuration.dtd">
<UWLConfiguration version="1.0">
    <ItemTypes>
        <ItemType name= ”uwl.task.webflow.TS8880003.SAP_ECC_HumanResources” connector=”WebFlowConnector” defaultView=”DefaultView” defaultAction=”viewDetail” executionMode=”default”>
            <ItemTypeCriteria systemId=”SAP_ECC_HumanResources” externalType=”TS8880003″ connector=”WebFlowConnector”/>
            <Actions>
                <Action name=”Approve” groupAction=”yes” handler=”UserDecisionHandler” returnToDetailViewAllowed=”yes” launchInNewWindow=”no”>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property name=”decisionKey” value=”1″ />
                    </Properties>
                    <Descriptions default=”Approve”/>
                </Action>
                <Action name=”Reject” groupAction=”yes” handler=”UserDecisionHandler” returnToDetailViewAllowed=”yes” launchInNewWindow=”no”>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property name=”decisionKey” value=”2″ />
                    </Properties>
                    <Descriptions default=”Reject”/>
                </Action>
            </Actions>
        </ItemType>
    </ItemTypes>
</UWLConfiguration>
```

Comment: Your xml has `”` instead of `"`

Answer (score 0):

Now i am getting new error "The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE UWLConfiguration PUBLIC "-//SAP//UWL1.0//EN" "uwl_configuration.dtd">
</UWLConfiguration version="1.0">
    </ItemTypes>
    <ItemType name="uwl.task.webflow.TS8880003.SAP_ECC_HumanResources connector"="WebFlowConnector" defaultView="DefaultView" defaultAction="viewDetail" executionMode="default">
    <ItemTypeCriteria systemId="SAP_ECC_HumanResources" externalType="TS8880003" connector="WebFlowConnector"/>
    <Actions>
    <Action name="Approve" groupAction="yes" handler="UserDecisionHandler" returnToDetailViewAllowed="yes" launchInNewWindow="no">
    <Properties>
    <Property name="decisionKey" value="1" />
    </Properties>
    <Descriptions default="Approve"/>
    </Action>
    <Action name="Reject" groupAction="yes" handler="UserDecisionHandler" returnToDetailViewAllowed="yes" launchInNewWindow="no">
    <Properties>
    <Property name="decisionKey" value="2" />
    </Properties>
    <Descriptions default="Reject"/>
    </Action>
    </Actions>
    </ItemType>
    </ItemTypes>
</UWLConfiguration>
```